# How to add input field value to the table rows dynamically in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux

How to add input field value to the table rows dynamically in reactjs and table row should have option to delete the row. Get the input value in array.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRdTa.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check how to create How to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that you can get a much better response to your question.

Comment: Try to be more specific, add your own code example, there are many ways to reach your goal

Comment: Hi, I am using redux field to get the field value and passing the value through a event..
Class EmailTable extends Component{
<Field name ="emailID" />
<Button onClick={this.addRow.bind(this)}>Add</Button>
}

Comment: please refer the below link..
I am trying to read Field value and push each field value to Field array. Also reset the Field input to null after adding the value. How to read the Field value and display at "remove" button. I have used field.firstname. Please assist.

https://jsfiddle.net/Mahaboob/75rh036o/7/